# Xamarin.Forms DLToolkit FlowListView How to get selected item?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, selecteditem

In my project I have to work with this plug-in: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView

Here is the part of my XAML:

```
    <flv:FlowListView 
        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
        FlowGroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Path=Letter}"
        FlowColumnCount="2" 
        FlowItemsSource="{Binding CitiesAlphabet}"
        FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding TapCity, Mode=TwoWay}"
        x:Name="CityList"
    >
```

What is the "**FlowItemTappedCommand**"? Is it `TapGestureRecognizer` instead of `ItemSelected`? How should I implement this command, and how can I get now selected (tapped) item in ViewModel?

Is there any detailed manual with examples how to work with this plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding CityTappedCommand}"
```

Implementation of the command:

```
public ICommand CityTappedCommand{ get; set; }
```

You can initialize it in the constructor of the viewmodel

```
CityTappedCommand = new Command(() => YourSub());
```

To get the selected item, you can add the following in your xaml:

```
FlowLastTappedItem = "{Binding SelectedCity}"
```

and then get SelectedCity in you viewmodel.

Comment: Hah you beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

> What is the "FlowItemTappedCommand"?

Yes, is probably just a command like tapped that can be bound to your itemVm.

> Is it TapGestureRecognizer instead of ItemSelected?

I'm not sure what you mean here, but essentially yes, when you tap the item it raises a command at your VM.

> How should I implement this command

Like any other command really.

> How can I= get now selected (tapped) item in ViewModel?

This is the problem with using under-documented nuggets off the web, who knows?

However, I'm just going to take a stab at this from looking at the source. Try:

```
FlowLastTappedItem="{Binding LastTappedItem}"
```

> Is there any detailed manual with examples how to work with this
> plug-in

The author has a blog and is visible on Stack Overflow, you should really point these comments at him, or his GitHub page, or at least tag the control in the question.

Comment: Yea, i have some problems with underdocumented nugets off the web, anyway ty for help!